# Content for one of the dynamically created tabs not showing

Tags: android, tabs

I have an android app that takes data from JSON and creates as many tabs as indicated in the JSON along with relevant content. 
On running the app, all my tabs show the contents but one of the tabs shows NO content.
I have implemented the tabs using fragment.

In the tab with no content, the content to be fetched from JSON are of spinner type. When I put a content of edittext type as the first content, then all the contents get displayed

Can you please tell me the possible reason?

Comment: share your code here

Comment: Code is long, but in the tab with no content, the content to be fetched from JSON are of spinner type. When I put a content of edittext type as the first content, then all the contents get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

if everything has been created dynamically then check that on that particular categoryid of fragment data is present or not(on postman), if data is coming from that categoryid of that fragment. then there must be mistake in any KEY name in model class.

Comment: In the tab with no content, the content to be fetched from JSON are of spinner type. When I put a content of edittext type as the first content, then all the contents get displayed.